# Css only in posts, wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to add css only in posts of my wordpress website. Which is the best way to do something like this?
I try to put my  in single.php and its work fine, but i thing there is better way to do something like that. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a different css that loads for the single posts , for that use the following code ,

```
    function single_post_css() {
        if(is_single()){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'single', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/single.css' );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'single_post_css' );
```

create single.css inside css directory.

Comment: You can add the code to child theme's function.php , and add single.css to child theme. I have updated the code. Don't forget to remove it from main theme.

Answer (score 1):

If your theme uses [**`body_class()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) in the body tag, you will have a specific css class for the single page `(.myclass)`, which you could use in the stylesheet;

```
add_filter('body_class','pd_body_class_add');

function pd_body_class_add($classes) {

  global $post;  // use Global $post

  if ( is_single() ) { 
    $custom_class = "myclass";
  }

    $classes[] = $custom_class;
    return $classes;
}
```

Add above function in your `function.php`.

---

**Example** (might be different for your theme):

```
.myclass .entry { color: #123edf; }
```